# vb.net increase gap between dynamically created textbox conrol

Tags: vb.net, textbox, margin, dynamically-generated

i have dynamically created textbox i want to increase margin between them  for, if i increase the font size they will not overlap each other. is there any properties which i can use . i already used

```
txtbox.top = txtbox.top +5
```

but it is pushing all text boxes to down i want to increase gap between text boxes

```
for i = 0 to pnl.controls.count-1

    pnl.controls(textboxD & i).top = pnl.controls(textboxD & i).top +5

next
```

i am using above code for moving toolboxes. thank you in advance

Comment: Try using a FlowLayoutPanel instead.  It will move the controls for you.

Comment: thanks flowlayoutpnael is working but the problem is now all label and textboxes are showing one bye one  is there any way i can show       Label : textbox      insted of Label <br>Textbox<br>Label

Comment: Try placing the Label and TextBox in a Panel or UserControl so that now it acts as one unit.

Comment: @Allex make sure the FLP is set to go left to right not top to down and also make sure it is wider than the 2 controls widths, otherwise it will wrap them automatically